# FogBugz and Git Integration

Tags: git, fogbugz

I'm trying to integrate Git with FogBugz.  I have tried following their guidelines here: http://help.fogcreek.com/8048/integration-with-git but it seems this only works with GitHub.  Does anyone know of a way to integrate directly on a Git setup?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Its generic GIT ;) you have to include the hooks that FogBugz can work with the repo. The last one is use a better bugtracker :D. http://help.fogcreek.com/8048/integration-with-git

Comment: Yes I already tried Generic Git and added the hook scripts but nothing gets posted to FogBugz...

Comment: Then check if the hooks are correct and if they are executable.